# Vector in skew coordinate system to cartesian coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformation

I have a skew coordinate system with axes **x**, **y**, **z’**, where **x** and **y** are orthogonal to each other. In the third dimension, the **z**-axis would be the orthogonal axis to **x** and **y**, but I don’t have **z**. Instead, I have axis **z’**, which is tilted by $\beta$ from yz-plane and by $\alpha$ from xz-plane. Here is plot for better clarity (the blue axes are the skew coordinate system that I have):

[image]

**My problem:** In this skew coordinate system, I have a vector or point ($x_0$, $y_0$, $z’_0$). I now want to tilt the xy-plane by $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so that it is perpendicular to the **z’**-axis, i.e. I want to create an orthogonal system with axes **x’**,**y’**,**z’**. (Yes, the task is not to change **z’** to **z**, but **x** and **y** to **x’** and **y’**).

**My question:** How do coordinates of ($x_0$, $y_0$, $z’_0$) change when expressed in this new coordinate system, i.e. I want ($x’_0$, $y’_0$, $z’_0$)?

**My approach:** For sure, the xy-plane would need to be first tilted by $\beta$ to the right and then by $\alpha$ upwards to be perpendicular to **z’**. However, the point ($x_0$, $y_0$, $z’_0$) is not rotated, but its coordinates need to be expressed in the new system. The first step, **x** to **x’**, would change the $x_0$ coordinate to $x’_0$, and I think it is simply
$$x’_0 = x_0 \cdot cos(\beta)$$
correct? I then need to tilt the **y**-axis by $\alpha$, but is it as simple as
$$y’_0 = y_0 \cdot cos(\alpha)$$
or do the two transformations affect each other (**x** and **y** are ortogonal and so are **x'** and **y'**...)? In other words, is my point ($x_0$, $y_0$, $z’_0$) in the new coordinates simply $(x_0 \cdot cos(\beta), y_0 \cdot cos(\alpha), z’_0)$?

And is there a more formal way of transformation? I was reading about transformation matrices, but failed to construct one for this problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that $0\lt\alpha\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\lt\beta\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Let $P(a,b,c)$ be a point on $xyz$ coordinate system.

Since $z'$ axis is a line whose equation is $$\dfrac{x}{\cos\alpha\sin\beta}=\dfrac{y}{\sin\alpha}=\dfrac{z}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta}$$
where $\vec v=(\cos\alpha\sin\beta,\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha\cos\beta)$ is an unit vector, a point on $z'$ axis is represented as
$$Q_t(t\cos\alpha\sin\beta,t\sin\alpha,t\cos\alpha\cos\beta)$$
So, we see that the $z'$ coordinate of $P$ on $xyz'$ coordinate sysytem is given by $t$ such that
$$\vec v\cdot \vec{PQ_t}=0$$
i.e.
$$(\cos\alpha\sin\beta,\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha\cos\beta)(t\cos\alpha\sin\beta-a,t\sin\alpha-b,t\cos\alpha\cos\beta-c)=0$$
i.e.
$$t=a\cos\alpha\sin\beta+b\sin\alpha+c\cos\alpha\cos\beta$$

Since $x'$ axis is a line whose equation is $$\dfrac{x}{\cos\beta}=\dfrac{z}{-\sin\beta}\quad\text{and}\quad y=0$$ the $x'$ coordinate of $P$ on $x'y'z'$ coordinate system is given by $t$ such that $$(\cos\beta,0,-\sin\beta)(t\cos\beta-a,-b,-t\sin\beta-c)=0$$
i.e.
$$t=a\cos\beta-c\sin\beta$$

Since $y'$ axis is a line whose equation is $$\dfrac{x}{-\sin\alpha\sin\beta}=\dfrac{y}{\cos\alpha}=\dfrac{z}{-\sin\alpha\cos\beta}$$ the $y'$ coordinate of $P$ on $x'y'z'$ coordinate system is given by $t$ such that $$(-\sin\alpha\sin\beta,\cos\alpha,-\sin\alpha\cos\beta)(-t\sin\alpha\sin\beta-a,t\cos\alpha-b,-t\sin\alpha\cos\beta-c)=0$$
i.e.
$$t=-a\sin\alpha\sin\beta+b\cos\alpha-c\sin\alpha\cos\beta$$

From what we've got, we see that a point $P(a,b,c)$ on $xyz$ coordinate system is represented as
$$\bigg(a,b,a\cos\alpha\sin\beta+b\sin\alpha+c\cos\alpha\cos\beta\bigg)$$
on $xyz'$ coordinate system, and is represented as
$$\bigg(a\cos\beta-c\sin\beta,-a\sin\alpha\sin\beta+b\cos\alpha-c\sin\alpha\cos\beta,a\cos\alpha\sin\beta+b\sin\alpha+c\cos\alpha\cos\beta\bigg)$$
on $x'y'z'$ coordinate system.

Therefore, we have a system
$$\begin{cases}x_0=a
\\y_0=b
\\z_0'=a\cos\alpha\sin\beta+b\sin\alpha+c\cos\alpha\cos\beta
\\x_0'=a\cos\beta-c\sin\beta
\\y_0'=-a\sin\alpha\sin\beta+b\cos\alpha-c\sin\alpha\cos\beta\end{cases}$$
Eliminating $a,b$ and $c$, we finally get
$$\color{red}{\begin{align}x_0'&=\frac{x_0}{\cos\beta}+y_0\tan\alpha\tan\beta-z_0'\frac{\tan\beta}{\cos\alpha}
\\\\y_0'&=\frac{y_0}{\cos\alpha}-z_0'\tan\alpha\end{align}}$$

Comment: So the basic idea is to create new unit vectors of axes x', y', z' expressed in the old unit vectors of axes x,y,z? Then a scalar product between each new unit vector and the orthogonal line to point P has to be zero (all expressed in the axes x,y,z, giving equations for t which is the same in both the skew and the orthognal system so that we finally get equations that can be solved for $x_0'$ and $y_0'$. Correct?

Comment: @Charles Tucker3 : Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Many thanks, got it! I still have 2 questions, would be nice if you comment on them: 1) From the red equations I can directly see the coefficients of the transformation matrix from (x,y,z') to (x',y',z'), correct? Is your method the most direct way of obtaining this matrix? 2) I wondered why you put y=0 in the second step...I guess this is because x needs to be rotated round the y-axis by $\beta$ in order to be perpendicular to $z'$ (becoming the $x'$ axis...)? And the y-axis needs then (3rd step) to be rotated around this new $x'$ axis by $\alpha$ to become $y'$ (perpendicular to x' and z')?

Comment: @Charles Tucker 3 : 1) Yes and I think yes. 2) Yes and Yes.